# R: overlay density plot with lines based on condition of a column

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

I have a dataframe that consists of one column of conditions (strings) and multiple columns of number values. For each column, I would like to create an overlaid density plot, where each line represents a condition. I have found many solutions to overlay each column as one line on the same plot, but not how to create the lines by grouping based on conditions. Since this is a large dataset, I would rather not specify the groups manually.

| condition | c2 | c3 | c4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| b | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| c | 3 | 1 | 2 |
| a | 5 | 0 | 1 |
| a | 2 | 4 | 3 |
| c | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| b | 2 | 3 | 3 |
| a | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| c | 3 | 1 | 2 |
| c | 6 | 0 | 2 |
| a | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| c | 1 | 3 | 1 |
| b | 4 | 3 | 0 |

Using this example data I would like to have one density plot for each of columns 2-4. There should be 3 lines per plot (representing a, b and c).

Preferably I would like to do this with ggplot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option is `ggdensity`

```
library(ggpubr)
out <- ggdensity(df, x = c("c2", "c3", "c4"), color = "condition",
         fill = "condition")
ggarrange(plotlist = out, ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
```

-output

[image]

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(condition = c("b", "c", "a", "a", "c", "b", "a", 
"c", "c", "a", "c", "b"), c2 = c(1L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 4L), c3 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 3L, 3L), c4 = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to overlay another line on each plot for the average density of all 3 conditions?

Comment: @keenan do you need `add = "mean"` i.e. `out <- ggdensity(df, x = c("c2", "c3", "c4"), color = "condition",
         fill = "condition", add = "mean")`

Comment: This adds a horizontal mean line for each condition. I was hoping for one line showing the mean density overall, regardless of condition. So essentially overlaying another density plot without considering condition at all.

Comment: @keenan Can you post as a new question as this may require more modifications

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-condition) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(value, color = condition)) +
  geom_density() + 
  facet_wrap(~ name)
```

returns

[image]

**Edit**
Thanks to Brenton M. Wiernik's comment, we could use `scales = "free"` to scale all plots seperately.

```r
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-condition) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(value, color = condition)) +
  geom_density(alpha = .3) +
  facet_wrap(~ name, scales = "free")
```

returns

[image]

Comment: I have too much variation between values in my normal dataset so I think I need to make each plot individually. Do I need to make a different longer dataframe for each one? Or is there an easy way to specify which column to use? Or to scale each one differently?

Comment: Add `scales = "free_x"` to the `facet_wrap()` function to all each facet (here variable) to be scaled separately.

Comment: @Matin Gal use `fill` instead of `color`.

Comment: Or use both. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = value, fill = condition)) + 
    geom_density(alpha = 0.5) +
    facet_wrap(~name, scales = "free_x") +
    theme_classic()
```

[image]